# Single @StreamListener to route different payload types to generic service classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am implementing a common library for multiple Spring Boot applications which will provide a simple interface to Kafka. I have chosen Spring Cloud Stream for the Kafka integration. This library must support multiple different payload types, however I'm having difficulty understanding how this can be done in a clean and generic way.

I know that I can implement multiple `@StreamListener` methods for each payload type, for example:

```
    @StreamListener(target = SinkBindings.INPUT, condition = "headers['X-Target-Type'] matches '.*\\.Person'")
    public void listenForMessage(Person payload) {
        // do stuff with payload
    }
```

However, this solution is not scalable for many different payload types. In an ideal world, I do not want the applications using this common library to even be aware of the Kafka listener methods. Instead, I would prefer to provide an SPI whereby consuming applications implement an interface such as that shown below, and the framework will call the implementing Spring bean and pass it the correct payload type.

```
public interface MessageHandlingService<T extends BaseClass> {

    void handleMessage(T payload);

}
```

For each payload type I wish to avoid having to implement a separate `@StreamListener` method, but this seems to be quite messy due to Java's type erasure. I'm wondering if there is a realistic way to route different payload objects to generic service beans with a single stream listener method?

Another idea which occurs is adding a `boolean support(Class<?> clazz)` method to the interface above, which would allow the library to check which class supports the payload, however this seems a little "hacky" (???).

Comment: I doubt it's possible for the individual applications to not be "aware of the Kafka listener methods", or at least the fact that you're using Spring Kafka Stream. After all, they'll need to provide the topic and SerDe class to deserialize their objects. Or are you planning on providing a list of all of those in the library? That would be bad design IMO.

Comment: Additionally to what Artem said below,  consider reading this section https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#content-type-management. What you are asking is impossible for one simple reason. Message comes in as `byte[]` - always. So we have no way of knowing which type you want to convert to until we access the type information from the handler method (e.g., StreamListener or function).

Answer (score 1):

The payload of an incoming message is converted exactly to expected type: there is no way to do otherwise with `@StreamListener`. Spring Cloud Stream approach with `@StreamListener` depends on the expected type of your method param. This is a signal for conversion. You can't convert your payload to type and then try to determine method to call using just `@StreamListener`. The `@KafkaListener` on the class level with `@KafkaHandler` on methods can help you here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.0.RC1/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener.

Also fully blown Spring Integration flow with its conversion capabilities can be used for such a logic.

See more about content type negotiation in the Docs: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#content-type-management